# User subscribes to newsletter even if checkbox is not checked

Tags: webforms, emails

I have a newsletter on my drupal page created with [simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews).

I have created [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform), that lets you apply for a job and it has "subscribe to newsletter" `Newsletter email checkbox`. When someone submits the form, I can see in the form results, that some people have there value "val" and some have empty string. But all people get subscribed no matter what the value was. Even if they did no check the checkbox.

How can I prevent that?